# how to install xcode on macos hight sierra without apple account

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on python programming language when I want to convert .py to .ipa (ios) but I don't have an apple account and I am missing ios sdk in xcode

I tried searching for xcode on the forums and all the forums pointed to the download at apple but I don't have an apple account

Comment: Create a free apple account?